# Apache NiFi already in use for an active callback or an InputStream created by ProcessSession.read(FlowFile) has not been closed

Tags: apache-nifi

I am getting following error in NiFi `ExecuteScript` processor.

```java
18:07:09 UTCERROR9e1d9c5e-0188-1000-ffff-fffffbc25817
10.42.62.250:8080ExecuteScript[id=9e1d9c5e-0188-1000-ffff-fffffbc25817] ExecuteScript[id=9e1d9c5e-0188-1000-ffff-fffffbc25817] failed to process due to org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: javax.script.ScriptException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=40d42213-2c7a-49a2-8c5d-5a7fc58bad2d,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1686706804350-73290, container=default, section=586], offset=6556, length=39642],offset=0,name=40d42213-2c7a-49a2-8c5d-5a7fc58bad2d,size=39642] already in use for an active callback or an InputStream created by ProcessSession.read(FlowFile) has not been closed in <script> at line number 37
- Caused by: javax.script.ScriptException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=40d42213-2c7a-49a2-8c5d-5a7fc58bad2d,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1686706804350-73290, container=default, section=586], offset=6556, length=39642],offset=0,name=40d42213-2c7a-49a2-8c5d-5a7fc58bad2d,size=39642] already in use for an active callback or an InputStream created by ProcessSession.read(FlowFile) has not been closed in <script> at line number 37
- Caused by: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<script>", line 37, in <module>
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.StandardProcessSession.validateRecordState(StandardProcessSession.java:3715)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.StandardProcessSession.validateRecordState(StandardProcessSession.java:3710)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.StandardProcessSession.transfer(StandardProcessSession.java:2349)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2736.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=40d42213-2c7a-49a2-8c5d-5a7fc58bad2d,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1686706804350-73290, container=default, section=586], offset=6556, length=39642],offset=0,name=40d42213-2c7a-49a2-8c5d-5a7fc58bad2d,size=39642] already in use for an active callback or an InputStream created by ProcessSession.read(FlowFile) has not been closed

- Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=40d42213-2c7a-49a2-8c5d-5a7fc58bad2d,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1686706804350-73290, container=default, section=586], offset=6556, length=39642],offset=0,name=40d42213-2c7a-49a2-8c5d-5a7fc58bad2d,size=39642] already in use for an active callback or an InputStream created by ProcessSession.read(FlowFile) has not been closed; rolling back session: {}
18:07:09 UTCERROR9e1d9c5e-0188-1000-ffff-fffffbc25817
10.42.62.250:8080ExecuteScript[id=9e1d9c5e-0188-1000-ffff-fffffbc25817] Processing failed: org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: javax.script.ScriptException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=40d42213-2c7a-49a2-8c5d-5a7fc58bad2d,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1686706804350-73290, container=default, section=586], offset=6556, length=39642],offset=0,name=40d42213-2c7a-49a2-8c5d-5a7fc58bad2d,size=39642] already in use for an active callback or an InputStream created by ProcessSession.read(FlowFile) has not been closed in <script> at line number 37
- Caused by: javax.script.ScriptException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=40d42213-2c7a-49a2-8c5d-5a7fc58bad2d,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1686706804350-73290, container=default, section=586], offset=6556, length=39642],offset=0,name=40d42213-2c7a-49a2-8c5d-5a7fc58bad2d,size=39642] already in use for an active callback or an InputStream created by ProcessSession.read(FlowFile) has not been closed in <script> at line number 37
- Caused by: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<script>", line 37, in <module>
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.StandardProcessSession.validateRecordState(StandardProcessSession.java:3715)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.StandardProcessSession.validateRecordState(StandardProcessSession.java:3710)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.StandardProcessSession.transfer(StandardProcessSession.java:2349)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2736.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=40d42213-2c7a-49a2-8c5d-5a7fc58bad2d,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1686706804350-73290, container=default, section=586], offset=6556, length=39642],offset=0,name=40d42213-2c7a-49a2-8c5d-5a7fc58bad2d,size=39642] already in use for an active callback or an InputStream created by ProcessSession.read(FlowFile) has not been closed
```

I am trying to run following script in NiFi `ExecuteScript` processor

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import os
import java.io
from org.apache.commons.io import IOUtils
from java.nio.charset import StandardCharsets
def find_pattern_in_xml(file_path, target_string):
    tree = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(file_path))
    root = tree.getroot()

    found_elements = []

    # Iterate through all elements in the XML tree
    for element in root.iter():
        # Check if the target string is present in the element text
        if target_string in element.text:
            found_elements.append(element)

    return found_elements
flowFile = session.get()
if flowFile is not None:
    try:
        stream_content = session.read(flowFile)
        text_content = IOUtils.toString(stream_content, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
        # flowfile_path = flowFile.getAttribute('sourceFileName')
        target_string = "~Indv"
        found_elements = find_pattern_in_xml(flowfile_path, target_string)

        # Print the found elements
        for element in found_elements:
            session.remove(flowFile)
            print(element.tag, element.text)
    except Exception as e:
        # Log the error and route the flowfile to failure
        log.error("Error processing flowfile"+ str(e))
        session.transfer(flowFile, REL_FAILURE)
session.commit()
```